# Why do I get this error ' at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" ' on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, go, deployment

I have deployed my application written with Go to Heroku. As soon as I open app it gives me error. I check logs it shows this error.
PS. I am listening by calling `http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), nil)`. I have set `PORT` environment variable to :80.

Comment: What is the exact error, because what you posted doesn't look like error. Heroku populates `PORT` automatically, you shouldn't set it yourself.

Comment: Please post the lines before this "error". You can see [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed](on herolu), H10 means it crashed, but you need to look at the previous logs. Also @MichałMłoźniak is right, remove PORT from your variable, heroku is already providing you the PORT to use at runtime...

Comment: If you (or Heroku) set PORT to `:80` than `":"+os.Getenv("PORT")` is one colon too much.

Comment: `
Starting process with command `login`
Process exited with status 1
login: Cannot possibly work without effective root`

here `login` is my root folder and my `Procfile` is like `web: login`